# How can I solve the following exercise with streams

Tags: java, functional-programming

In the following exercise I should keep all the Rooms, which have SmartLamps in it. How can I solve this with streams? Since each SmartLamp has attribute Room I need to stream over rooms and lamps. I tried to do it with anyMatch, but cannot find a working solution. Can somebody help? ( I know how to solve it without streams)

```
public class SmartHome {

private final List<Room> rooms;
private final List<SmartLamp> lamps;

public void deleteRooms() {
 rooms.stream().anyMatch(lamps.stream().map(SmartLamp::getRoom));
}
}
```

Code gives error:
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream to Predicate<? super Room>"

Comment: `Collection`s like `List`s have a method [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Comment: Alternatively, [Stream.filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) allows you to only pass elements matching a prediate to the next operation in your pipeline.

Comment: You can use `.stream()` and filter the bad rooms out (`.filter()`). After that, you can collect the rooms and assign it to your `this.rooms`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not wrong to use `anyMatch` but only at the wrong place:

```
public void deleteRooms() {
    rooms = rooms.stream().filter(r -> lamps.stream().map(SmartLamp::getRoom).anyMatch(r::equals);
}
```

but the above is not ideal since you have to iterate over the list of lamps for each room. Extracting all rooms which appear in the lamps list beforehand can help:

```
public void deleteRooms() {
    Set<Room> smartRooms = lamps.stream().map(SmartLamp::getRoom).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    rooms = rooms.stream().filter(r -> smartRomms.contains(r)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or using List.removeIf

```
public void deleteRooms() {
    Set<Room> smartRooms = lamps.stream().map(SmartLamp::getRoom).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    rooms.removeIf(r -> !smartRomms.contains(r));
}
```

Comment: This looks great! but the second example with filter has the not operator when it shouldnt!

Stream filter result contains everything that returns true :)

Comment: @bgore Thank you for pointing that out. Copy pasted and didn't payed attention.

Comment: I though that I can solve this with only stream but I see it is not possible and we always need to use collections too..Am I correct?

Comment: Isn't your `removeIf` equivalent to `rooms.retainAll(smartRomms);`?

Answer (score 2):

> I should keep all the Rooms, which have SmartLamps in it.

OK, so you can do like this ...

```
public class SmartHome {

private final List<Room> rooms;
private final List<SmartLamp> lamps;

void deleteRoomsWithoutSmartLamps() {
  var goodRooms = roomsWithSmartLamps();
  // This line will remove the bad rooms from the list
  rooms = rooms.stream().filter( r -> goodRooms.contains(r)).collect(toList())
}

// This method gives you a list of rooms with smart lamps
public List<Room> roomsWithSmartLamps() {
 var goodRooms = lamps.stream().filter( lamp -> lamp.isSmartLamp() ).map(lamp -> lamp.getRoom()).filter(room != null)collect(toList());
  
  return goodRooms;
}
}
```

Does this solve your problem ? Tell me in the comments.

Comment: No the rooms have no lamp attribute...The lamps have a room attribute

Comment: Added an edit. Check it out

Comment: Am I correct that this method would only return the relevant rooms, however I need to apply the method to the List<Room> and change it with streams...

Comment: See next edit to original post

Comment: Does it solve your problem now ?

Comment: I'm trying...I pushed the method filter(room != null) to the front since room cannot be accessed in this sequence above

Comment: If this solves your problem please feel free to upvote and accept the answer so others can find it and reuse it with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

```
lamps.stream().map(SmartLamp::getRoom).anyMatch(rooms::contains);
```

The predicate does not expect a stream, you would need to make a lambda `room -> ...`.

However you already have to make a stream for mapping lamps, so I would start with that stream. And really `contains` is not very good, but fine enough.

A `Set<Room>` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
lamps.stream()
         .map(SmartLamp::getRoom)
         .filter(rooms::contains)
         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Nice! But this would need to do additional operation afterwards, since I need to change the List<Room> rooms. The filtering is perfect, but can I somehow apply any operations to rooms from within this stream? (I don't think it is possible)

Comment: Yes. You should use flatmap() then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe anymatch isnt what you would like here. Any match is a stream method that returns true or false if anything in the stream matches what you want.

But regardless you would want a Predicate

which is of the form

```
List<Room> lampRoomList = lamps.stream().map(SmartLamp::getRoom).ToList()
//predicate is in the filter method
List<Room> roomsWithLamps = rooms.stream().filter(room.toroom -> lampRoomList.Contains(Room)).toList();
```

where room in the second line means object in the stream. in your case a room.

The first line is to hold the list of all rooms in lamps so you do not need to to the mapping for every room.

you can read more about predicates here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-predicate-with-examples/